# Decrement-or-delete in SQL

Tags: sql

In SQL, I've got a table that maps token=>count; it's a dict where the default value is 0.  If I want to increment a token, I can say:

```
insert into my_table (token, count)
values (my_token, 1)
on duplicate key update count = count + 1;
```

and if a token doesn't exist yet, it's inserted with count=1.  Nifty.

Is there a similarly easy way to do the opposite in SQL, i.e., "given a token, decrement its count, and if count becomes 0 then just remove the record entirely"?  I can think of longer ways to do it, but nothing as concise as the above.

Comment: Can you give an example of what sort of action would trigger this decrement?  In your increment example, you are working on the row that is being added. How would you determine which row(s) to modify for a decrement.

Comment: In the decrement example, I'm working on a row that's being decremented; you're given my_token.

Comment: +1 Symmetry is nice, and searching for it is noble.  Too bad we can't always find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to use transactions as follows (my SQL is a bit rusty but you should get the idea):

```
-- begin transaction
update my_table set count = count - 1 where id = '7'
delete from my_table where id = '7' and count = 0
commit
```

This will ensure the atomicity of the decrement-and-delete operation.

However, one other possibility you may want to consider - don't remove it at the point where it reaches zero. Since you say the default value is zero anyway, just leave the row in there with a value of 0.

Of course, your queries will need to change to adapt to that. If you have one that lists active tokens, it will change from:

```
select token from my_table
```

to:

```
select token from my_table where count > 0
```

The decrement SQL in that case must be careful not to push the token count down to -1, so it would become:

```
update my_table set count = count - 1 where id = '7' and count > 0
```

That simplifies your SQL at the decrement time. If you still want those rows with zero-count to disappear, you could have another process that runs periodically to sweep them all up:

```
delete from my_table where count = 0
```

That's just some alternatives to consider - if you really want them gone at the exact time their count reaches zero, then use the transaction method above.

Comment: Right, that's the longer way.  :-)  I guess it's not bad, but I figured there might be a more symmetric approach.

Comment: You could delete the row in an after trigger, but that would probably not be faster than the above 2-statement transaction, and might be slower.

Comment: I considered leaving them around, but it's fast and simple to delete the record, and I like the simplicity of the "nonzero if in table, else zero" invariant.

Answer (score 0):

You want triggers. (I take it this is MS SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Um, wouldn't the answer be the obvious:

```
insert into my_table (token, count)
values (my_token, 0) 
on duplicate key update count = count - 1;
```

Comment: No, I see nothing there which will ever delete a record.